# Continuously ping a target and return status with notification

Tags: linux, ping, automation

This is for CTFs (Capture The Flag) like [hackthebox](https://www.hackthebox.eu/) and [tryhackme](https://tryhackme.com/). I'm using Kali Linux and Manjaro Linux.

I'm trying to make a module for polybar. I want to have a script to ping a server (once every 1-10 seconds) in the background and a polybar module to display the current status of the server. For example:

- Server down -> Can't ping -> Display IP in red.
- Server up -> Display IP in green

Additionally, I want it to do a `notify-send "target up"` whenever the server goes down->up and `notify-send "target down"` when it goes up->down.

I can make a script to `curl` in intervals but `curl` can take a lot of time to return a result. I'm not sure how I would use just `ping` to have the status bar update as wanted.

How can I make a script/module to continuously check a server's status with pings like so?

Answer (score 0):

The Linux *ping* tool has a `-c` option for specifying the number of requests and the `-W` option for specifying how long to wait (in seconds) for each reply.

If *ping* doesn't receive any replies (e.g. you specified `-c 1` but it received zero), it exits with a "failure" status. You can check for this in your script.